# Hide posts from users with a specific role

Tags: wp-query, user-roles

Simply put, I need to hide all posts on the frontend if they are written by authors with a specific role. The role I have created is called 'Suspended'.

I'm happy with putting a simple IF statement around the loop which prevents posts from a certain role ID from appearing. Preferably though it would be something I can enter into the WP_Query.

I Can't use user ID as there would be xx number of users with the same role.

Does anyone know how this could/ would be done? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) to build a list of suspended authors` ids, then use that list with minuses for inversion as [author parameter in query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters).

Comment: Nice idea, I'll give it a try.