# Show posts from specific roles

Tags: query-posts, user-roles

I'd like to use query_posts() to show only posts from editors and administrators on my home page so that normal authors can post on their own pages, but not affect the home page.

Edit :

Thanks for the quick reply, I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to php, do you think you could give me the code I require? I'm currently using this, but getting no posts returned despite having several posts by an administrator:

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'administrator' ) );
$admins = $wp_user_search->get_results();
$args = implode(',', $admins);
query_posts("author=$args");
```

Comment: This is exact opposite of this question [Hide posts from users with a specific role](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22039/hide-posts-from-users-with-a-specific-role) check out my answer there and if it fits I will probably close this as duplicate.

Comment: @Rarst: the answer to this question is exactly the same minus the minus sign ( - ) in the query parameters but i guess its still something a lot of people would look for and not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Code you are after:

```
<?php
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'administrator' ) );
$admins = $wp_user_search->get_results();
$admin_ids = array();
foreach($admins as $admin) {
    $admin_ids[] = $admin->ID;
}
$args = implode(',', $admin_ids);
query_posts("author=$args");
?>
```